# Test to find nature of the critical points fails.

Tags: calculus

I have a question. I need to find the critical points of $x^4+y^4-2x^2+4xy-2y^2$ . And I have to test the nature of the critical points. I have had found 3 critical points. (2 minimum points) But I have a problem with $(0,0)$. Because I get $D=0$ and thus is the test inconclusive, but how can I do this?
Thank you!

Comment: it is an implicit function $x^4+y^4-2x^2+4xy-2y^2=0$ or a function of two variable $f(x,y)=x^4+y^4-2x^2+4xy-2y^2$  ?

Answer (score 1):

You have$$f(x,y):=x^4+y^4-2(x-y)^2\ .$$
It follows that
$$f(t,t)=2t^4>0\quad(t\ne0)$$
and
$$f(t,-t)=2t^4-8t^2=-2t^2(4-t^2)<0\qquad\bigl(0<|t|<2\bigr)\ .$$
Now draw conclusions.